# I am having trouble separating my cards for war game. They both display on top of each other

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get my cards to display 2 different boxes for the cards. If I hover just right with inspector I can see both cards are there, but I am having difficulty separating the two side by side. I am mostly trying to follow a tutorial but it has you do a lot of the work on your own, and I don't want to advance until I have this completely ready for the next task it gives me. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>
            War Cards!
        </title>
        <style>
            .icard
            {
                position: absolute;
                padding: 10px;
                height: 200px;
                width: 150px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-radius: 15px;
                background-color: white;
                display: inline-block;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
            }

            .hand
            {
                position: relative;
            }

            .players
            {
                float: left;
                width: 49%;
                min-height: 300px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="start"></div>
            <div id="message"></div>
            <div id="board">
                <div id="player1" class="players">
                    <div class="score"></div>
                    <div class="hand"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="player2">
                    <div class="score"></div>
                    <div class="hand"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="action">
                <button id="btnBattle" type="button" class="btn">
                    Fight!
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            $('document').ready(function() {
                var suits = ["spades", "hearts", "clubs", "diams"];
                var cardFace = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"];
                var cards = [];
                var players = [[], []];
                var firstRun = true;
                var gameOver = false;
                var fightButton = document.querySelector("#btnBattle");
                var p1 = document.querySelector('#player1 .hand');
                var p2 = document.querySelector('#player2 .hand');

                fightButton.addEventListener('click', battle);

                function battle()
                {
                    if (firstRun)
                    {
                        firstRun = false;
                        buildCards();
                        shuffleArray(cards);
                        dealCards(cards);
                    }
                    attack();
                    console.log('Works');
                }

                function attack()
                {
                    if(!gameOver)
                    {
                        var card1 = players[0].shift();
                        var card2 = players[1].shift();
                        var pot = [card1, card2]
                        p1.innerHTML = showCard(card1, 0);
                        p2.innerHTML = showCard(card2, 0)

                        // Check Winners
                        // Update Scores
                    }
                }

                function showCard(c, p)
                {
                    var move = p * 40;
                    var bgColor = (c.icon == 'H' || c.icon == 'D') ? 'red' : 'black';
                    var bCard = '<div class="icard" style="color:'+ bgColor +'">' + c.num + ' &' + c.suit + ';</div>';
                    console.log(c, move);
                    return bCard;
                }




                function buildCards()
                {
                    cards = [];
                    for (s in suits)
                    {
                        var suitNew = suits[s][0].toUpperCase();
                        for(n in cardFace)
                        {
                            var card = {
                                suit:suits[s],
                                num:cardFace[n],
                                cardValue:parseInt(n) +2,
                                icon:suitNew
                            }
                            cards.push(card);
                        }
                    }
                        console.log(cards);
                }

                function dealCards(array)
                {
                    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                    {
                        // swaps between remainder 0 and 1, which signifies player[0 OR 1], and then pushes that onto parameter,(array), which
                        // is cards which is an array, at the index of for loop [i]
                        var m = i % 2;
                        players[m].push(array[i])
                        }
                    console.log(players)
                    }


                //
                // function dealCards(array)
                // {
                //     for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                //     {
                //         if(i % 2 === 0 )
                //         {
                //             players[0].push(array[i]);
                //         }
                //         else
                //         {
                //             players[1].push(array[i]);
                //         }
                //
                //     }
                //     console.log(players);
                // }
                //

                function shuffleArray(array)
                {
                    for(var x = array.length -1; x > 0; x--)
                    {

                        var ii = Math.floor(Math.random() * (x + 1))
                        var temp = array[x];
                        array[x] = array[ii];
                        array[ii] = temp;

                    }
                    console.log(cards);
                    return array;
                }
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! When asking a question, it's good to only include the code involved with what you're trying to solve. This makes it easier for people to see the exact part of your code that isn't working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed to add the players class to the player 2 element.

```
 <div id="player2" class="players">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zkw9s4an/

Comment: Ah such a simple issue, I can't believe myself. Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

Add `css` to the player 2 `div` to move it `margin left` by the amount you  need.

```
#player2
{
  margin-left:10%;
}
```

Refer [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yhmtnpxb/).